# Bug with moving a boolean from main class to seperate class

Tags: java, swing

I've been making an installer for a few of my friends for adding mods to Minecraft.
I removed all of my static variables and methods from my project(except the main method of course) and just added objects to the main method so I could call methods from other classes(without the methods in the other classes being static[Thanks to MadProgrammer for suggesting this to me :D]) And now when I try to call a boolean in my seperate class(FileHandling) it returns false no matter what, but if I print out the boolean in the main class it changes between true and false(like it should)
Why is this and how can I fix it?

**Below is my previous error, which is still occurring, but is not the 'main idea' of this post**

I created a method(inside the class FileHandling) called fileChooserCheck. What it does is it gets the directory for installation defined by the user by a JFileChooser and sets that to modDir, or, if the user doesn't specify, it sets the installation directory to the default directory, which is the File 'defaultDir'. Whenever I run the method fileChooserCheck, it doesn't change the Path modDir, when I try to call it(modDir) it returns null.

How can I make it so that fileChooserCheck actually changes the Path modDir?

If you see anything in my code that you is sloppy and/or could/needs to be improved please tell me, I've only been programming with Swing for a few days, and Java for almost a week[I only know one other programming language[which is pretty basic)]

EDIT: Updated and slimmed down the code

### Main Class

```
public class MainInstaller extends JFrame {

//File moddir;
Path modDir;
URI bioForums = URI.create("http://bio-mc.com/forum");
String mcDir = "C://Users//" + username + "//AppData//Roaming//.minecraft";
File defaultDir = new File("C://Users//" + username +  "//AppData//Roaming//.minecraft");
Font consoleFont = new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 13 + 1/2);
Font checkFont = new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 14 + 1/2);
String[] minimapsArray = { "REI's Minimap", "Zan's Minimap" }; //An array of optifine versions, get manually later
Object minimap;
int yInterval = 22;
boolean enabled = false;
boolean optifine, invtweaks, armorhud, statuseffecthud, tabbychat, spc, chatbubbles, map = true;
boolean fcLaunched = false;

JPanel installPanel, modsPanel, consolePanel;
Box box, box1;
JLabel title;
JLabel modsel;
JLabel author;
JTabbedPane tabbedpane = new JTabbedPane();
JComboBox<?> minimaps; //The drop down menus to select the versions of optifine and  invtweaks
JButton installButton;
JButton fileButton, forumButton, threadButton;
JTextArea console;
JTextField mcdir; 
JFileChooser fc;

public MainInstaller() { //MainInstaller Constructor

    //The First Tab(Installer)
    installPanel = new JPanel();
    installPanel.setLayout(null);
    Insets insets = installPanel.getInsets();
    installButton = new JButton("Install!");
    installButton.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    Dimension size = installButton.getPreferredSize();

    mcdir = new JTextField();
    mcdir.setText("C:/Users/" + username + "/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft");
    mcdir.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    size = mcdir.getPreferredSize();
    mcdir.setBounds(139 + insets.left, 80 + insets.top, size.width + 5, size.height);
    mcdir.setEditable(false);

    fileButton = new JButton("...");
    size = fileButton.getPreferredSize();
    fileButton.setBounds(mcdir.getX() + 280, mcdir.getY() - 1 + insets.top, size.width, size.height + 3);   
    fileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fcLaunched = true;
            //Create the FileChooser and define it a bit    
            if (fc == null) {
                    fc = new JFileChooser("C://Users//" + username + "//AppData//Roaming//.minecraft");
                        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                }

            //Show the file Chooser
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fileButton);

            fc.setSelectedFile(defaultDir);

            modDir = moddir.toPath(); //Changed what was previously 'moddir.toPath();' into what it is now b/c 'moddir' is a String type, not a File type

            //Process the results
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                mcdir.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
            } 
        }
    });

    installButton.setBounds(139 + insets.left, mcdir.getY() + 50 + insets.top, mcdir.getWidth() + fileButton.getWidth(), size.height + 40);

    installPanel.add(author);
    installPanel.add(forumButton);
    installPanel.add(threadButton);
    installPanel.add(installButton);
    installPanel.add(mcdir);
    installPanel.add(fileButton);

    //The Second Tab(Mod Selection)
    modsPanel = new JPanel();
    modsPanel.setLayout(null);
    insets = modsPanel.getInsets();
    JLabel modsel = new JLabel("Select the mods you installed");
    modsel.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 15));
    size = modsel.getPreferredSize();
    modsel.setBounds(5 + insets.left, 2 + insets.top, size.width + 15, size.height); 

    //Adds all the mod checkboxes

    JCheckBox invBox = new JCheckBox("InvTweaks");
    invBox.setFont(checkFont);
    size = invBox.getPreferredSize();
    invBox.setBounds(2 + 1/2 + insets.left, 2 + (yInterval*2) + 1/2 + insets.top, size.width, size.height); //Y = 44
    invBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            invtweaks = !invtweaks;
        }
    });

    modsPanel.add(modsel);
    modsPanel.add(invBox);
    modsPanel.add(mapBox);

    tabbedpane.addTab("Installer", installPanel);
    tabbedpane.addTab("Mod Selection", modsPanel);

    //Add everything to the frame
    add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(tabbedpane);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { //Main Method

    final MainInstaller frame = new MainInstaller();
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    final FileHandling file = new FileHandling();
    file.createBaseFolder();
    file.copyMods();

    frame.installButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(frame.invtweaks == false) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No mods are enabled");
            } else {
                // (?) Install mods here?
                try {
                    file.copyMods();
                    System.out.println("Installing Mods");
                    System.out.println("Source: " + file.invSource);
                    System.out.println("Target:" + file.invTarget);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error!" + e);

                }
            }
        }});
}
```

}

### FileHandling Class

```
public class FileHandling {
MainInstaller mi = new MainInstaller();

Path modDir = mi.modDirPath;
Path source = Paths.get("C://Users//Gannon//Desktop//Java//workspace//ModPack Installer//test.txt");
Path target = Paths.get("C://Users");

Path invSource = Paths.get("mods//invtweaks.jar");
Path invTarget = Paths.get(mi.modDirPath + "//InventoryTweaks-MC1.6.2-1.55-b56.jar");

public void fileChooserCheck() {
    if(mi.fcLaunched == false) {
        mi.modDirPath = mi.defaultDir.toPath();
        System.out.println("Unchanged: " + mi.modDirPath);
    } else if(mi.fcLaunched == true) {
        mi.modDirPath = mi.fc.getSelectedFile().toPath();
        System.out.println("Changed: " + mi.modDirPath);
    }
}

public void copyMods() throws IOException {
    fileChooserCheck();
    try {
        if(mi.invtweaks == true) {
            Files.copy(invSource, invTarget);
            System.out.println("Trying to copy!");
        } else if(mi.invtweaks == false ) {
            System.out.println("InvTweaks isn't selected!");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The Copying Failed!" + e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Never post this much code. Debug it until you find the relevant parts and post those.

Comment: @Sotirios I slimmed down the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main class you define modDir but you never assign it a value.  You do have this line, but it's commented out:

```
//modDir = moddir.toPath();
```

Also I would like to warn you that having two variables with the name name, but different case is a bad idea:

```
String moddir;
Path modDir;
```

Something better would be:

```
String modDir
Path modDirPath
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it is doing the same thing(bug). I updated the code to what I changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little trouble following exactly what's going on here, but I'm a little concerned that you're creating two entirely separate instances of your MainInstaller class: one ('frame') created inside MainInstaller's run method, and the second ('mi') is created as a field in your FileHandler class definition.  Since none of the fields in MainInstaller appear to be static, it might become easy to get your references crossed by changing a boolean in one instance and checking the same boolean in another instance.

A quick test for this issue could be to specify some of the fields (e.g. the booleans) as static and reference them appropriately.  However, if it were me, I'd strongly consider re-defining the MainInstaller class as a singleton.  I'll willfully-expose my inexperience here by attempting to explain what I mean:

- Add a private static field of type MainInstaller called 'instance' to your MainInstaller class definition, initialize it to null.
- Add a public static method (with no args) that returns a MainInstaller object called 'getinstance'
- This method should check if the 'instance' field is null - if so, define it to be a new instance of MainInstaller.  Then, just return 'instance'.
- Then, any time you need to define/access a MainInstaller object, do so through the 'getInstance' method.

The advantage here is that you can still use non-static fields and methods where necessary, but ensure that you don't have multiple instances floating around where you don't expect them, and I'd be willing to wager that you don't intend to create multiple instances of MainInstaller.

- I forgot to mention that typically you'd also make your constructor private too, just to ensure that no other classes can create additional instances, and instead should use the getInstance method.